# Simplifying a Javascript Form Submit

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit

I like to use javascript to submit a form. I'm new with javascript and I don't know how to simplify the next code: (This code is working but I think it's possible to simplify):

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$actual_link = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
?>
<form id="countryDE" method="post" action="geo-country.php">
<input type="hidden" name="gobackto" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($actual_link);?>">
<input type="hidden" name="countrycookie" value="DE">
</form>
<form id="countryIT" method="post" action="geo-country.php">
<input type="hidden" name="gobackto" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($actual_link);?>">
<input type="hidden" name="countrycookie" value="IT">
</form>
<form id="countryUS" method="post" action="geo-country.php">
<input type="hidden" name="gobackto" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($actual_link);?>">
<input type="hidden" name="countrycookie" value="US">
</form>
<form id="countryCA" method="post" action="geo-country.php">
<input type="hidden" name="gobackto" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($actual_link);?>">
<input type="hidden" name="countrycookie" value="CA">
</form>
<?php
echo $_COOKIE["cbccountry"];
?>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" title="Germany" onclick="submitformDE()">Germany</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="Italy" onclick="submitformIT()">Italy</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="United States" onclick="submitformUS()">United States</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="Canada" onclick="submitformCA()">Canada</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitformDE()
{
document.forms["countryDE"].submit();
}
function submitformIT()
{
document.forms["countryIT"].submit();
}
function submitformUS()
{
document.forms["countryUS"].submit();
}
function submitformCA()
{
document.forms["countryCA"].submit();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why do you have forms at all if the inputs are hidden? Why not just submit the values on clicking the link - using ajax? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: If you use named submit buttons, the name of the button is submitted when the form is submitted if it's the one used for submission. No script required. Why are you submitting a form at all? Why not use plain links with search queries?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I like to use a script to prevent search engines follow the links... but I'm thinking now that search engines does not follow POST forms. I'm right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tracker1/9pfxL4Lz/

Just used styled submit buttons with the name matching the key/value you want to pass.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
$actual_link = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
?>
<style type="text/css">
button.link {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:0;
  padding:0;
  color:#00f;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="geo-country.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="gobackto" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($actual_link);?>">
    <button class="link" type="submit" name="countrycookie" value="DE">Germany</button>
    <button class="link" type="submit" name="countrycookie" value="IT">Italy</button>
    <button class="link" type="submit" name="countrycookie" value="US">United States</button>
    <button class="link" type="submit" name="countrycookie" value="CA">Canada</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

//UPDATE

http://jsfiddle.net/v5dejopw/11/

```js
function submitform()
{
    var submit=document.forms["test"]["country"].value;
   switch (submit) 
   {
     case 'Germany': 
        submit = 'Germany';
     break;
        case 'Italy': 
        submit = 'Italy';
     break;
        case 'United States': 
        submit = 'United States';
     break;
        case 'Canada': 
        submit = 'Canada';
     break;
   }
    
    

}
```

```html
<body>

<form name="test" id="test" method="post" onsubmit="return submitform();">
<input type="hidden" name="gobackto" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($actual_link);?>" onsubmit="return submitformDE();">
<input type="hidden" name="countrycookie" value="DE">
<input type="submit" name="country" value="Germany" class="submitInput">

<input type="hidden" name="gobackto" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($actual_link);?>">
<input type="hidden" name="countrycookie" value="IT">
<input type="submit" name="country" value="Italy" class="submitInput">

<input type="hidden" name="gobackto" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($actual_link);?>">
<input type="hidden" name="countrycookie" value="US">
<input type="submit"  name="country"value="United States" class="submitInput">
    
<input type="hidden" name="gobackto" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($actual_link);?>">
<input type="hidden" name="countrycookie" value="CA">
<input type="submit"  name="country" value="Canada" class="submitInput">
 
</form>
```

Comment: So if the value of *submit* is 'Germany' you assign the value 'Germany'?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend looking into making post requests to the server with javascript, rather than having so many form elements. My way of solving this problem would be to have a single form with a radio block, and tie a click event to the radio elements that will automatically submit the form.